# Struggling to merge and display two arrays (result of two query) into one

Tags: php, arrays

I am using an old version of PHP symfony MVC framework. In the controller I have written two different query

```
$query1 = \FrontGate\Models\Events::query(); 
$query2 = SELECT Events.ID, count(EventTicket.ID) as NumOfTickets from EventTicket INNER JOIN Event On Event.ID = EventTicket.EventId where ..
```

The first query is a database model query. The result of first query is like following.

```
$array1 = Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => ID
                            [table] => DatabaseModelTable
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => GuestListID
                            [table] => DatabaseModelTable
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Name
                            [table] => DatabaseModelTable
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => UpdatedAt
                            [table] => DatabaseModelTable
                        )
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => UpdaterPeopleID
                            [table] => DatabaseModelTable
                        )
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => ConcRV
                            [table] => DatabaseModelTable
                        )
                )
```

the size of this array and number of elements are fixed for this array.

Result of 2nd Query is

```
$array2 = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [NumberOfTickets] => 21
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [NumberOfTickets] => 12
)
```

The size of the second array is not fixed. There can be more or less element.

The relation between the two array is ID. which is one of the value in first array.

How to merge these two arrays.

How can i bring the value of Number of tickets (from the second query result ) in the first array so I can display the result as the picture below.

[image]

Comment: If you have the two result arrays, and both have the same number of elements, just loop over the first or last array and use `array_merge()`?

Comment: the array structures of two array are different. Will array merge work?

Comment: Well, the inner array is associative, and I see each array has different keys. So all keys and values will be preserved, unless two arrays have the same keys. The merge should work properly.

Comment: well array merge is not working . probably i need to use a foreach loop. but i am just stuck and cant figureout how to use that.

Comment: Yeah you need foreach loop. That's why I said "loop over the first or last array". I will post an answer explaining it real quick.

Comment: We do not have a [mcve] here.  Your desired result contains `3` and `1009` and `Beach Party` and `Afternoon Drinks`, but your sample input doesn't contain these values.  Maybe set up a realistic demo on phpize.online and share that link with us so that we can immediately toil and test our advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example after executing the queries, if you get back `$array1` and `$array2`, then you can do the following:

```php
$result = [];

foreach ($array1 as $i => $value) {
   $result[$i] = array_merge($value, $array2[$i]);
}

var_dump($result); // merged!
```

Then you can pass down `$result` to your view.
Note that this requires both of the arrays to have the same number of elements to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the two array don't have the same number of element. I have removed the elements from the first array to make post easily readable.